# How to access "Registered Addons" page in IDA?

Tags: ida

How to access "Registered Addons" page in IDA?

[image: https://images3.programmersought.com/607/1e/1ee40de29f228b09e5aaf37d36d26f2f.png]

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the feature is only supported after IDA v7.2

Go to . `Help-->About-->Addons` [source](https://bbs.pediy.com/thread-262835.htm)

Add-ons is the button in About page.